# Getting Colour Coordinates like TEXCOORD0 for blurring

Tags: c#, xna, hlsl

I'm trying to get to grips with HLSL... I understand how you can specify a specific pixel to fetch texture colours from however this ignores tint, using `COLOR0` as an input for the function I can get the tint for the pixel however.. as far as I can tell I am unable to access  some kind of property that I would have assumed would be called `COLORCOORD0` so that I can grab the colour tints of the surrounding pixels.

How would you fetch colour tints from pixels other than the one the function is currently dealing with?

Also, what units do the x and y coordinates use? If I remember correctly I remember reading long ago that `{0f, 0f}` would be the center of the window, `{-1f, -1f}` would be the top left corner and `{1f, 1f}` would be the bottom right corner; is this correct? Does this mean your shaders will vary person to person depending on the size of the game window due they use?

Comment: You would need to first render the (un-blurred) scene to a texture, then, to draw the blurred scene, look up values from the surrounding points in that texture to be able to do this.

Comment: Thanks! You should have this an answer! I can't mark it as answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to first render the (un-blurred) scene to a texture, then, to draw the blurred scene, look up values from the surrounding points in that texture to be able to do this.

(moved to an answer as suggested).

Answer (score 1):

The [XNA Bloom Sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/bloom) is your place to go for a good example of how to do blurring.

Basically you render your scene to a render target. Bounce it to another target via a multi-tap blur shader in one direction (horizontal or vertical), then draw it to the screen via a blur shader in the other direction.

You can also down-sample to half size, then upsample, using bilinear filtering to get additional blurring without requiring more texture samples.